# Webbrowser c# Получить исходный код страницы после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Доброго времени суток, помогите решить проблему :

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("url");
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;


            while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("continue").InvokeMember("click");
            while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            var txt = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
```

В переменную `txt` записывается код страницы полученный при `webBrowser1.Navigate("url");` как можно получить код после программного нажатия на кнопку `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("continue").InvokeMember("click");`?

Comment: Циклы `while` выбросить. Использовать событие `DocumentCompleted`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, спасибо, помогло